# Does an uneven and/or moving surface affect quality when using a solar filter?

Tags: astronomy, imaging, astrophotography

I have chosen to make my own solar filter using Baader as opposed to Mylar or anything else based on these: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/25204/6805 and http://irwincur.tripod.com/mylar_vs__baader.htm and others.

My last solar filter was the product which is no longer available direct from Celestron (I'm not even sure what it was made with).

**My questions**:

Does "flapping in the wind" baader effect image quality? See the images below to understand what I mean...

Is it possible to achieve a better taut fitting when making my own?

As seen here

[image]

it is not flat or tight like this glass one is

[image]

Comment: Related Support http://www.celestron.com/c3/support3/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=2378

Comment: ![No Image in comments](http://media.skyandtelescope.com/images/Solar_filter_products_m.jpg)  The range of safe filter materials for solar viewing is wide, as is the form such filters can take. The most versatile materials are black polymer and aluminized polyester film (black and green glasses, respectively), which are popularly used both for visual observing and with optical aids.
Sky & Telescope photo by Chuck Baker.  **BE SAFE**

Comment: What do you mean by versatile? They can be made completely flat and taught? My question is: "Does "flapping in the wind" baader effect image quality?"

Comment: Those materials should fit snugly and remain semi-taught.

Answer (score 1):

The baader film should not be stretched tight. To do so will damage the optical properties. The proper mounting is not taught because to do so risks stretching the material. It should be mounted loosely. Mounted loosely with a few wrinkles will not effect the performance